# Is it ok to use int to convert CHARACTER(2) to SMALLINT in DB2?

Tags: integer, db2, character, type-conversion

I have two tables having the same value in different data types.

One is `CHARACTER` length 2 and another is a `SMALLINT`.

How can I compare both in a where clause?

I have `INT(CHAR_COLUMN_X) = SMALLINT_COLUMUN_X`. Is it fine or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be fine. If it's a `SMALLINT` column, then you could just go to that instead of an `INT`

```
CAST(CHAR_COLUMN_X AS SMALLINT) = SMALLINT_COLUMN_X
```

If there is a value in CHAR_COLUMN_X that is not castable to a smallint (a letter, for example), then DB2 will throw a [`-420` SQL Code](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n420.htm).

Comment: Well, if it's not a number, how would you expect it get converted to a number? Basically, what you ask depends on your application, but in general, no `X` cannot be converted to `24`. :)

Comment: No, what I am looking for is to convert if possible, suppress the error otherwise returning no match.

Comment: Have a look at this other question, it might provide some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565275/test-for-numeric-value